# react native don't show loop iteration number when click on button

Tags: react-native, for-loop, jsx

sorry for my English language

I wrote a function for push JSX elemnts in an array and return that:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Button} from 'react-native-paper';

const buttonLoop = () => {
    const items = []
    for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        items.push(<Button icon="camera" onPress={() => alert(i/* Problem is here*/)}>Loop {i/* It work true*/}</Button>)
    }

    return items;
}
```

as you can see i inside of element work truly, and show 1 for Button1 and show 2 for Button2.
But when i click on button it show "3" for both button, I want show "1" for Button1 and "2" for Button2

in JQuery i had't this problem, why it don't work true and what's solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it like this,
When you click the button the i you are referring to is pointing to the one in the loop which has the value 3 so the way to fix this is passing the i as a parameter like below

This happens when using var due to closures, you will have to use the let keyword.

```
const ButtonLoop = () => {
  const items = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

    items.push(
      <Button icon="camera" onPress={() => alert(i)} title={i}>
        Loop {i}
      </Button>
    );
  }

  return items;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it return "[object Object]" when click on buttons

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example 
this question would provide you a good description of the reason :)